# getData() in CuratorFramework not returning any data

Tags: apache-zookeeper

When I run

```
get <path>
```

in zookeepr CLI, I get the following

```
192.168.0.102
cZxid = 0x2e93
ctime = Wed Feb 06 15:12:20 GMT+05:30 2013
mZxid = 0x2e93
mtime = Wed Feb 06 15:12:20 GMT+05:30 2013
pZxid = 0x2e93
cversion = 0
dataVersion = 0
aclVersion = 0
ephemeralOwner = 0x13cae2a97ed001f
dataLength = 13
numChildren = 0
```

For the same path I am trying to get the data as follow

```
client.getData().forPath(path);
```

I deserialize the data. But it is not returning anything.
I also tried

```
client.getData().inBackround().forPath(path);
client.getData().watched().inBackGround().forPath(path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using `inBackground()`.

`inBackground()` causes the request to execute asynchronously. By removing `inBackground()` you should get the desired outcome.